# SQL Server : selecting data based on ids pointing to a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a view based on two tables.

Member:

```
ID  Lang1_ID  Lang2_ID - all tinyint
1   2         3
2   2         4
3   1         4
```

Language:

```
ID  Title - tinyint, varchar(50)
1   English
2   French
3   Spanish
4   Portuguese
```

I wish to create a view with all the titles containing:

```
member_id, Lang1_Title, Lang2_Title
```

Needed result:

```
1  French  Spanish
2  French  Portuguese
3  English Portuguese
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id member_id, l.Title Lang1_Title, l2.Title Lang2_Title
  FROM Member m LEFT JOIN 
       Language l ON m.Lang1_ID = l.ID LEFT JOIN
       Language l2 ON m.Lang2_ID = l2.ID
```

Output

```
| MEMBER_ID | LANG1_TITLE | LANG2_TITLE |
-----------------------------------------
|         1 |      French |     Spanish |
|         2 |      French |  Portuguese |
|         3 |     English |  Portuguese |
```

**[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1d43/6)**

And the view

```
CREATE VIEW viewname
AS
SELECT m.id member_id, l.Title Lang1_Title, l2.Title Lang2_Title
  FROM Member m LEFT JOIN 
       Language l ON m.Lang1_ID = l.ID LEFT JOIN
       Language l2 ON m.Lang2_ID = l2.ID
```

And use it

```
SELECT * FROM viewname
```

**[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00656/1)**